# Count a Torah scroll as the tenth in a minyan?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, minyan

There is a widespread perception in  non-traditional congregations that the Torah scroll can count as a tenth to make a minyan.

However, the [Code of Jewish Law](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.55.4?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) does not mention that.  It only says that some authorities allow a six-year-old boy to count as the tenth in a minyan, provided he holds a Chumash or Sefer Torah and understands what he is doing [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayyim 55:4]. Some, led by the Ri (Rabbi Isaac ben Samuel the Elder of Dampierre) reject this view. The current practice is that some permit it only in extraordinary circumstances [The Rosh and Mordechai and Hagahot Maimoni Chapter 9 of the Laws of Prayer].

So, is there any basis in our tradition for this practice in non-traditional synagogues?

Answer (score 6):

R David Sperling at yeshiva.co [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=7713) addresses your question and brings a number of rejected opinions - to be clear the *halacha* remains that a Torah scroll does not count as a tenth in a minyan

> **In regards the question of using a Sefer Torah as the "tenth man" in a
>   minyan – yes this does have a vague hint of a source**. Firstly, the
>   Talmud (Brachot 47b) when discussing forming a minyan for saying zimun
>   before grace after meals (with Hashem's name in it), says "Said Rav
>   Huna, "**Nine and the Aron [Kodesh] join up [to be counted as ten]**". The
>   Talmud immediately rejects this and says "Is the Aron a person!". This
>   then may be the (rejected) source for the idea that the Sefer Torah
>   counts for a minyan.
>
> However, we do find some reference in halacha to some form of using a
>   sefer Torah for a minyan. The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Haim 55,4) talks
>   about including a boy less than bar-mitzvah age as the tenth for a
>   minyan, and writes that this is forbidden. The Rema adds that there
>   are those that in a time of need do rely on using a child, as long as
>   he is holding a Chumash in his hands. The overwhelming consensus of
>   Rabinic opinion is not to rely on this opinion even in times of need
>   (see Mishna Brurah there).
>
> **The source for the idea that a minor holding a chumash or Sefer Torah
>   might be counted for a minyan is discussed by the Rosh** (Berachot 7,
>   20) where he discusses at length the opinions that allow one child to
>   be counted towards a minyan, and he writes "The only source for this
>   [counting a child who is holding a chumash] is Pirkei d'R. Eliezer,
>   regarding Ibur Shanah [declaring a leap year]. There, it mentions a
>   Sefer Torah. **It says that R. Eliezer requires ten for Ibur Shanah, and
>   if we lack one, we bring a Sefer Torah**. It does not say that the minor
>   holds it. Even if there is such a source regarding Tefilah, this is
>   only for a Sefer Torah or Chumash, i.e. one Sefer of the Torah written
>   on parchment. Chazal did not have [printed] Chumashim like we do.
>
> **The Yerushalmi says "a minor and a Sefer Torah, we include them for
>   10."** This means a minor or a Sefer Torah, just like nine men and the Aron. The Halachah does not follow the Yerushalmi. Some texts of the
>   Yerushalmi say "a minor and a Sefer Torah, we include *oto* (him, or
>   it)." This is like the custom (that the minor holds the Sefer). Or,
>   perhaps it means that a minor may be counted among the seven required
>   Aliyos."
>
> **From here we see that in fact there is a situation where a Sefer Torah
>   makes up a minyan (for declaring a leap year) according to one
>   opinion, and perhaps even for a minyan for prayer, according to the
>   Yerusalemi Talmud. However, the halacha is not like this source**, and
>   we do not use a Sefer Torah (nor a child) as a "tenth man" for a
>   minyan. {In extreme situations a community should consult there Rabbi
>   as to the advisability of relying on the minor opinions that allow
>   counting a child who is holding a Sefer Torah for a minyan}.

Comment: Thanks.  Where in the Yerushalmi?

Comment: To be fair to Rav Huna in Berachot 37b, he talked about "nine who appear like ten", meaning that, since you can't count Jews, it's not obvious whether there are 9 or 10!

Comment: I have seen references to this Yerushalmi as 7:2 but haven't seen it inside

Comment: @mbloch [Yerushalmi Brachot 7:2 (53b)](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1107.htm) קטן וספר תורה עושין אותו סניף א"ר יודן כיני מתניתא קטן לספר תורה עושין אותו סניף מאימתי עושין אותו סניף.  רבי אבינא אמר איתפלגון רב הונא ורב יהודה תרויהון בשם שמואל חד אמר כדי שיהא יודע טיב ברכה.  וחרנה אמר שיהא יודע למי הוא מברך.

Comment: @magicker72 thanks for this !

Answer (score 1):

For those asking to see the Yerushalmi inside, it was too long to include in a comment. There is indeed a Yerushalmi in Berakhot 7:2--it adds the Sefer Torah as an afterthought in its discussion of the minor: תלמוד ירושלמי (וילנא) מסכת ברכות פרק ז
מתני' נשים ועבדים וקטנים אין מזמנין עליהן עד כמה מזמנין עד כזית. רבי יהודה אומר עד כביצה: גמ' ר' סימון בשם ר' יהושע בן לוי ר' יוסי בן שאול בשם רבי קטן עושין אותו סניף לעשרה. והתני אין מדקדקין בקטן א"ר יוסי קיימא רבי סימון ר' חנינא ר' סימון בשם ר' יהושע בן לוי לשני קטנים נצרכה שאם היה קטן עושין אותו [דף נג עמוד ב] ספק. ספק עושין אותו ודאי ר' יהודה בר פזי בשם ר' יוסי תשעה נראין כעשרה מה מזמנין מסוימין אלא אפי' קטן ביניהן ר' ברכיה א"ר יעקב בר זבדי בעא קומי ר' יוסי כמה דברים אמורים תמן קטן עושין אותו סניפין לעשרה ומר אף הכא עושין אותו סניף לשלשה. מה תמן שמזכירין את השם עושין אותו סניף כאן שאין מזכירין את השם לא כל שכן. א"ל והא אינו כל שכן תמן על ידי שהן אומרים את השם עושין אותו סניף. וכאן שאין קורין את השם אין עושין אותו סניף. תני קטן וספר תורה עושין אותו סניף א"ר יודן כיני מתניתא קטן לספר תורה עושין אותו סניף מאימתי עושין אותו סניף. רבי אבינא אמר איתפלגון רב הונא ורב יהודה תרויהון בשם שמואל חד אמר כדי שיהא יודע טיב ברכה. וחרנה אמר שיהא יודע למי הוא מברך

And here's that Pirkei D' Rabbi Eliezer inside for posterity. Not only does the sefer Torah make up the minyan but they get a bat kol...

פרקי דרבי אליעזר פרק ח
בשלשה מעברין. רבי אליעזר אומר בעשרה, שנאמר [תהלים פב, א] אלהים נצב בעדת אל. ואם נתמעטו, מביאין ספר תורה ופורשין אותו לפניהם. ונעשין כמין גרן עגלה, ויושבין גדול לפי גדלו וקטן לפי קטנו, ונותנין פניהן למטה לארץ ופורשין את כפיהן לאביהם שבשמים. וראש הישיבה מזכיר את השם, ושומעים בת קול שצווחת ואומרת בלשון הזה [שמות יב, א ב], ויאמר ה' אל משה ואל אהרן לאמר, החדש הזה לכם. ומעון הדור אינן שומעין כלום, אלא כביכול אינו יכול לשכן שכינה ביניהם. ואשריהם העומדין במקום ההוא בשעה ההיא, שנאמר [תהלים פט, טז] אשרי העם ידעי תרועה, ה' באור פניך יהלכון, באור פניו של הקדוש ברוך הוא הן מהלכין: